# How to trace something like this in HTML and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Supposedly, the game is tracing a line (vertical, horizontal, diagonal).

```js
 $("li.card").mouseover( function() { 
   $('#'+this.id).addClass('permahover');
});
```

```css
body{
 margin: 0 50px;
 background-color: #ddd;
}

li.card{
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color:white;
 border:1px solid #ddd;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:25px;
}

li.permahover{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Shetch</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
 <ul style="list-style:none">
 <li class="card" id="p1">I</li>
 <li class="card" id="p2">I</li>
 <li class="card" id="p3">I</li>
 <li class="card" id="p4">I</li>

 </ul>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

It's like sketching or tracing the letter "I". It is working with the hover, try hovering it from the top to bottom, so you can get my problem.

The one I need is, through mouse click or mouse drag something. Like I am clicking the first box down to the bottom.

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you elaborate a bit more? you want the "I" to be "draw" automatically?

Comment: @mrlew , no, manually. This is a kiddie game, like a kid should learn how to write letter "I". something like that. That line in the center is a guide.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is; what you you want to happen that isn't happening?

Comment: @VahnMarty so the kid should click in each div to turn it red?

Comment: It is like drawing on a paper. Imagine letter I, and there is a 'broken-line' which is a guide to draw/write it. It is like holding your ballpen/pencil to trace the letter 'I', but in my case you are holding your mouseClick to draw the line.

Comment: imagine the code has no hover effect. How I can I change the background-color from white to red, using mouseClick or idk or any mousevents that will help my problem.

Comment: will the whole thing grid?

Comment: im working on a code right now wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `on.("click", ...)` would be trivial to add the necessary class to do what you want to achieve.

**Update**

You can also keep track of the mouse events to see if a 'drag' event has occurred while hovering over the elements, See sample code for ***that*** at the bottom of the answer

See sample below using ***click***:

```js
$(function() {
  // on click, add the class to the element clicked
  $('li.card').on('click', function() {
    $('#' + this.id).addClass('permahover');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 50px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li.card {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
li.permahover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul style="list-style:none">
    <li class="card" id="p1">I</li>
    <li class="card" id="p2">I</li>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

I am still trying to see if you can do it while 'dragging' the mouse (which I believe is what your ultimate goal is)

---

### UPDATE

This is a way to keep track of whether the mouse is moving while the button is down (i.e. dragging) - using an external flag to determine if we should add the class or not.

See sample below using ***drag***:

```js
$(function() {
  // keeps track of mouse state (down | up )
  var isDown = false;

  $(".container")
    .on('mousedown', function() {
      //console.log('down');
      isDown = true;
    })
    .on('mousemove', function() {

      if (isDown) {
        //console.log('dragging');
      }
    })
    .on('mouseup', function() {
      //console.log('up');
      isDown = false;
    });

  $("li.card").hover(function() {
    //console.log('down? ' + isDown);
    if (isDown) {
      $('#' + this.id).addClass('permahover');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 50px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li.card {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
li.permahover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul style="list-style:none">
    <li class="card" id="p1">I</li>
    <li class="card" id="p2">I</li>
    <li class="card" id="p3">I</li>
    <li class="card" id="p4">I</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hey mate, do you know how will this works on mobile? It's not working on mobile browsers. And this game supposedly in mobile.

Comment: @VahnMarty It will not work on mobile - there is no concept of `hover` on mobile (which this solution is based on) - you never mentioned mobile in the original post :(

Answer (score 2):

I seem to understand the goal of this program, is it to help kids learn trace letters or anything using mouse?

See if this is what you're looking for, kinda same approach with ochi though.

```js
$(function() {
  var gridsize = 10;
  var count;
  var draw = false;

  for (x = 1; x <= gridsize; x++) {
    count = 0;
    for (y = 1; y <= gridsize; y++) {
      count++;
      $("#grid-container").append('<div id="' + x + '-' + y + '"  class="gridtile"></div>');
    }
    $("#grid-container").append('<br />');
  }

  $("#grid-container").on('mousedown', function() {
    draw = true;
  });

  $("#grid-container").on('mouseup', function() {
    draw = false;
  });
  
  $("div.gridtile").mouseover(function() {
   if(draw){
     $("#" + this.id).addClass("selected");
    } 
  });


});
```

```css
.gridtile {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-left: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}

#letter {
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 17em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
  z-index: -1;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid-container">
  <div id="letter">I</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your idea mate. Maybe I can use this in future.